# Max date removal and uaing last buisness date in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, max

```sql
Select max( date) from t1 t where a.calendar_ date= t.date
```

This query creating issue when month ends on weekend or on holiday. This query joins with another table so I need a query by using which I can get correct date.

Comment: And how do you know when a holiday is?  You need a table that has that information.

Answer (score 0):

"On holiday" is hard because they are regional and change from year to year. You should keep a table full of dates that are holidays so that you can exclude them with something like:

```
Select max(date)
from t1 t 
LEFT JOIN holidays h on t.date = h.date
where
  h.date IS NULL AND --not a holiday
  (1 + TRUNC (t.date) - TRUNC (t.date, 'IW')) NOT IN (6,7) AND -- not a weekend, regardless of region

  a.calendar_date= t.date
```

ps; I've no idea where your `a` alias came from